# Caret in textarea doesn't automatically pass new line (only in chrome)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

```
<textarea cols="152" rows="5">
Keep pushing space key after
the end of this sentence, you will notice that caret wouldn't pass new
row and stay put, start pushing space key now
</textarea>
```

When i just keep pushing space key after "start pushing space key now", caret doesn't automatically passes to new line at the very end of line. How can i get caret pass to new row at the end of row automatically? Is there any css solution for that? And only Chrome has this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome (and a number of applications) the cursor won't jump to the next line until you enter a non-"whitespace" character (so spaces will never drop it down a line). If you observe after keying in enough spaces to move the cursor all the way to the right edge, typing any other character (a number, letter, or punctuation), you will drop down a line. This is simply the way chrome handles textareas, and is not configurable.

On an unrelated note, "^" is a caret.