# Behavior of cursor in the end of texarea element in different browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser

I have the following issue with behavior of cursor in the end of textarea element. If I enter some text devided with spaces and then enter only spaces: in Chrome cursor stops in the end of line and line breaking happen when another symbols are entered, in Firefox cursor breaks line with last word from previous line.

The question is: is it possible to implement behavior from Chrome to Firefox?

I need behavior such as in Chrome, but Firefox have its own behavior.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Caret in textarea doesn't automatically pass new line (only in chrome)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38591391/caret-in-textarea-doesnt-automatically-pass-new-line-only-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems in last version of Firefox cursor behavior was fixed. The question is not actual already